# Reorder row values based on corresponding data

Tags: python, pandas

I've been looking for a solution to this for awhile and can't seem to find one. What I have is 5 columns used as ID codes for invididuals and 5 more columns that indicate their height. My goal is to rank the ID's BASED ON their corresponding height. Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Person ID                                  Person Height (in)              
 ID1    ID2     ID3     ID4     ID5         ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
 201566 202331  203500  203924  1628390     76  65  83  75  73
 202329 203081  203090  203468  203994      69  72  80  71  76
```

Expected Outcome:

```
Person ID (Ranked by Person Height)             
ID1     ID2     ID3     ID4     ID5
202331  1628390 203924  201566  203500
202329  203468  203081  203994  203090
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `sorted` and re-create your dataframe after that

```
l=[[y for _,y in sorted(zip(X, Y))] for Y , X  in zip(df1.values.tolist(),df2.values.tolist())]
sorteddf=pd.DataFrame(l,columns=df1.columns)
sorteddf
Out[20]: 
      ID1      ID2     ID3     ID4     ID5
0  202331  1628390  203924  201566  203500
1  202329   203468  203081  203994  203090
```